# Ubuntu Touch - Locking Telegram

Tags: ubuntu-touch, logout, telegram

I have set up Telegram on my M10 tablet and it works a treat. The whole family use the tablet and I want to lock the Telegram account so only I can use it. Just like you can do when you use the Telegram app for Windows. How do I activate the account lock, so only I can use it? I see you can add another account and log out of accounts, but all I want to do is lock my account.

Comment: I think it's a missing feature and I'm afraid it looks like it's not going to arrive soon: http://pad.lv/1448444

Comment: Thanks for the update. That is a shame that it will not bedelivered any time soon as it is already in the Windows version. Hopefully not a case of Ubuntu disceimination lo.

Comment: I think it is right that at least the Ubuntu version be at the same level as the Windows version. There is the ability to lock it in Windows, so why do we have to wait, without a time frame?